# Looking for a basic textbook

Tags: reference-request

Beyond basic arithmetic, my knowledge of Mathematics is nil.

I will sit a standardized test soon where knowing the following areas inside out is a must: pre-algebra, elementary algebra, intermediate algebra, coordinate geometry, plane geometry, and trigonometry.

So, I am looking for a textbook that covers the aforementioned areas at least.

What are your suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: How soon is *soon*? If you have the ability to learn all this material in a short time (several weeks? a few months?), then you're much more gifted in math than I am. Also, isn't the purpose of the test to correctly place you mathematically? Metaphorically speaking, why would you want to convince others that you're an expert swimmer when you don't yet know how to swim? Aren't you afraid of drowning later when you have to swim in the middle of an ocean?

Comment: January 2013. Assuming that I do grasp those areas the test requires, I won't be "drowning later" on, now will I?

Comment: Looking for **a** textbook that covers, what, 4 or 5 years of secondary-level mathematics? If there is such a textbook, you'll need a forklift to move it.

Answer (score 2):

With my students I have been trying to use a video games as part of my test prep.  I find that the game environment helps to keep students engaged with the content.

One of the ones that I've been using is called [The Lost Function](https://www.atltgames.com/products/episodeone/).  The nice thing about it is that it actually teaches concepts instead of just allowing players to practice them.  I really like the depth or the material and how accessible it is.

Also you can use the free video resources from [kahn acadamy](http://www.khanacademy.org/) they are pretty good for students that want to get ahead, but I (personally) find the videos a bit to long.  For highly motivated students they will be able to learn pretty effectively.

Answer (score 0):

- [Mathematics for the Nonmathematican, Morris Kline](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486248232);

It's not really a textbook, but it's going to be a good book for you, it includes lots of references, most of them are already on public domain such as [Whitehead's Introduction to Mathematics.](http://archive.org/details/anintroductiont01whitgoog) which is also a great book.

- [Prelude to Mathematics, W.W. Sawyer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486244016)

Another good book that is not a textbook, but will reveal some interesting areas on mathematics to you.

- [College Algebra with Trigonometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0077350103)

As a real textbook on college algebra, I'm using this one.